# ScrollView inside a ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I have one ViewPagerIndicator, that bring me a fragment, inside this fragment I have one ScrollView

My ViewPager xml:

```
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/cover_image2e3" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:padding="10dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeDogstar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="215dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDogstar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumLorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Loremipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum"
            android:textColor="@color/branco"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My onCreate in Activity:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new TestFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    PageIndicator mIndicator = (PageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

The question is: why my Scroll don't work? I can make the slider horizontally (for the ViewPager) but inside the fragment I can't scrolling vertically, or whatever action.

In ViewPagerIndicator disables something? How can I make enable the scroll?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to scroll in a ViewPager

Comment: How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is small, most likely. Your relativelayout is only 215dp in height, and everything else is wrapping content. So there is most likely simply nothing to scroll

Try setting your relative layout's height, in the fragment, to `match_parent`, and the scrollview's height to `match_parent` (if desired, of course), and have longer text, to test scrolling

Comment: The text makes the scroll, before making the ViewPagerIndicator, I was with android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip and worked right.